# Dual space of Sobolev functions with homogenous neumann BC

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz-domain with outward normal vector $\nu$ and let us take a look at the Sobolev-spaces $H^1:=H^1(\Omega)$, $H^1_0:=H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $H^1_{\nabla_0}:=H^1_{\nabla_0}(\Omega):=\{u\in H^1(\Omega)\ : \ \nabla u\cdot\nu=0\}$.

I know that (one type of possible characterizations) of the duals of $H^1:=H^1(\Omega)$ and $H^1_0:=H^1_0(\Omega)$ are given by

$$(H^1)^*=H^{-1}_0,\quad (H^1_0)^*=H^{-1}.$$

Now to my  first question: How can we characterize the dual of $H^1_{\nabla_0}$ and how is this dual related to $H^{-1}_0$ and $H^{-1}$? I would, at least, expect $H^{-1}_0\subset(H^1_{\nabla_0})^*$ since $H^1_{\nabla_0}\subset H^1$.

My second question: Can anyone recommend a good book/paper/article/lecture notes etc. on that matter (not necessarily in regard to Sobolev spaces but to dual spaces in general)?

Comment: Is $(H^1)^* = H_0^{-1}$ really true? E.g., in one dimension, $\Omega=(0,1)$, every $H^1$ function extends to the endpoints, and so $f\mapsto f(0)$ is an element of $(H^1)^*$. But it does not correspond to anything I would call $H_0^{-1}(\Omega)$.

Comment: It's probably not true. I tried to find a source but could not validate my claim. I thought that I've seen it in a lecture, but I am not sure of it.